# Comparing Two dates only with month and year in PHP

Tags: php, date

Let me explain the scenario.

1. I have "Month(Any month from 01 TO 12)" and "Year(For Example 17 for 2017" in my local variables.
2. I want to compare it with Current Month and Year.

.

```
    $month = 04;
    $year = 17;
    if ($month.'-'.$year > current month & year)
    {
     echo "not expired";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "expired";
    }
```

3. For example:

```
$old_month = 03;  // March
$old_year = 17;   // 2017

$new_month = 05;  // May
$new_year = 17;   // 2017
//how to compare and determine which month&year is old one or new one ?
```

Searched a lot in google and SO posts, but couldn't find any solution. Please help me.

NB: I have only month and year in my hand to compare it with current month and year.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I agree with @JohnConde - You also should have posted the db schema and representive values as well as the RDBMS you are using, since this looks to be db-related. Your question is unclear and too broad at the same time. So, is this db-related?

Comment: @JohnConde : Sorry, I know the rules, but this case I dont know how to make my question the right way as I am not accessing any of the values from tables or from my local database. I get the month and date from a remote API call.

Comment: ok; I'm not getting a response from my comment. If you're not going to bother to at least say *"No Fred, it's not db-related"*, then take it up with answers below. @PraveenGeorge I'll pass on this question and vote to close as unclear until we/I know which animal we're really dealing with here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh sorry, Its nt db related, the month and date is cming from a remote API call in the form like MOnth as 01, 02....12... and year like 17 for 2017 and 18 fro 2018.

Comment: @PraveenGeorge That detail to which you may think as being minor, could very well make or break the answers given and the question also. *Which* and what kind of API are we talking here? Details stand to be very important to the outcome of  answers given and potentially more, since at this point, there hasn't been an accepted answer (yet); but that stands to change in the course of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast the following code worked fine for me.

```
$currentDate=date('d/m/Y'); // taking current date

$expirationDay = 31;
$expirationMonth = 12;
$expirationYear = 2017;

$date2 = $expirationYear.'-'.$expirationMonth.'-'.$expirationDay;
$date2 = date_create($date2);
$date2 = date_format($date2,"d/m/Y");

if($currentDate <= $date2)
{
  echo "not expired";
}
elseif($currentDate > $date2)
{
  echo "expired";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to compare dates to each other. It's cleaner and easier to read as DateTime obejcts are comparable.

I used `DateTime::createFromFormat` since the dates you have from the API aren't going to be in a standard format for PHP and this makes it easier for PHp to handle.

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('my', $month.$year);
$now  = new \DateTime('midnight');
if ($date > $now) { 
    echo "not expired"; 
} else { 
    echo "expired"; 
}
```

Comment: somebody's got it out for you John :( df?

Comment: I think its revenge downvotting since I was critical of the other answers

Comment: You can do it simply with mktime, without using any classes.

Comment: @TahaPaksu Why are you afraid of classes?

Comment: @John Conde : I dont know what is happening here. Anyhow let me try this solution :)

Comment: I'm not afraid of them, I'm just using one liners where I can.

Comment: @JohnConde Yeah, I thought about that also. I voted to close this question as unclear, OP isn't responding to what I thought was [a valid question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736977/comparing-two-dates-only-with-month-and-year-in-php#comment74517195_43736977) under it.

Comment: Don't make code for difficult to maintain for the sake of making it one-liner. That's  a bad practice.

Comment: And you don't have the right to downvote the answers you don't like.

Comment: @TahaPaksu Yes, I do. If I think an answer is low quality I indicate it by downvoting it. That's how this site works.

Comment: @TahaPaksu *"And you don't have the right to downvote the answers you don't like"* - If I may John... Taha; it's not that John thinks he doesn't like it, it's probably because he may have thought that your answer was incorrect and/or not fit for the job. John is very good at what he does and answering questions like this. However, the question is unclear and you should see the comment I left the OP under their question. If people downvote for being nasty; believe me John isn't like that and I can vouch for his credibility and honour and integrity.

Comment: What makes an answer low quality? 1. it's wrong, 2. it only contains code, it lacks explanation, 3. it's not an attempt to answer the question.. etc. What makes my answer a "low quality" answer?

Comment: Ok, can you both say to people that they shouldn't use mktime() in their codes? I guess it's not like mysql versus mysqli?

Comment: 1. Your answer contains code which was not designed to do this kind of work 2. There's much better ways to do this in PHP 3. It's difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @TahaPaksu *"can you both say to people that they shouldn't use mktime() in their codes?"* - I for one did not downvote your answer or any others for that matter. I am not that good with date stuff as John is, so I have no say in this really. I originally thought that the question was db-related and for that, I would have been able to help. You also can't be certain that John downvoted you neither; there are others in this question.

Comment: @JohnConde : I have some problem with this code, its not working as expected.

Comment: That's not enough to go on. Do you get an error? What values do you have? If you have a working example you can ask a new question showing your code and what values you have so we can try it ourselves and let you know what's wrong.

Comment: @JohnConde: I am getting incorrect values on the variables when I try to echo them, and the comparison fails most of the time. I have updated the question.

Comment: Still can't tell you what's wrong until you add the rest of the code you are using. Otherwise all I can do is guess.

Answer (score 1):

@Praveen George i hope you want to do it like below try this with date():

```
<?php
$searchingDate = '05-17'; // your variable which contain month and year
if($searchingDate == date("m-y")){ // date("m-y") return current month and year in format like('05-17) if both are equal then it match 
    echo "match";
}
else{
    echo "did not match";
}
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. You should read, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This doesn't actually do what they are looking for either

Comment: @ John Conde  as i understand, OP is looking for this case